# Creating AOM goal models on Enterprise Architect

Tags: diagram, enterprise-architect

I have difficulty in adding new custom elements for drawing goal model diagrams. I checked all the available elements, I couldn't find similar elements for creating goal model diagrams. I can find the actor elements but the goal and quality goal elements seems not present.

Any ideas on importing these elements from external sources and defining their relationship properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After several months of research, i found out there is no enterprise modelling tool that supports this type of agent diagrams. One way to solve it is to implement this diagram type on any modelling tool that supports the extension of UML models using profile diagram.

- find uml elements with similar properties as the elements in the model
- create a profile diagram by extending the metaclass of UML elements selected using UML stereotypes, tagged values and constraints.
- Import the visual representation of the elements (svg images works fine) on the stereotypes.
- Implement a new diagram type using the profile diagram that was created.